# ModuleNotFoundError after pip install on venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv

I'm a little new to package management and trying to recreate a python environment using pip. I've called the following commands...

Created venv:

```
sudo python3.6 -m venv ./venv
```

Activated:

```
. activate ./venv/bin
```

Installed requirements.txt:

```
sudo pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt
```

The modules appear to install correctly, but after running the application it as if I've installed nothing:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hjson'
```

It's the same for other modules.

What have I done/not done to screw this up? Which directory should I be checking for installed packages?

I'm using opensuse Leap 15.0

Comment: `. activate ./venv/bin` doesn't look like a proper activation command. Try `source ./venv/bin/activate`, you should see the venv name in prompt if activation was successful. Another thing is that you don't need `sudo` to create or use the venv, although it probably has nothing to do with the error you get.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling it actually does seem to activate the virtual environment successfully I do see the venv in the prompt. I'll adopt your suggestion though it seems to fit with what I'm now seeing elsewhere, not sure why I have my syntax in my notes.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering how you solved this issue, as I think I have the same issue and I can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3.6 comes with pip 10 which is outdated. You should update it to latest version.

After activating the virtual environment with

```
source ./venv/binc/activate
```

Update the pip with

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I you still having problem, ensure that pip is installed. If not installed, install relevant version.

E.g. for ubuntu:

```
apt install python3.6-pip
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ramazan. When I follow the above I get "/usr/bin/python: No module named pip"

Comment: I've since managed to upgrade pip. Sadly I still see the same problem.

Comment: Scratch that, I had gotten my pythons confused momentarily, it seems to have solved the problem now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @goose I'm wondering how you fixed your issue, as I believe I have a very similar issue, and I can't seem to find the solution

Comment: @casualcoder pretty sure I just wasn't using the right python environment. If you're having a similar problem then check your python path is the same for both pip install and the code you're trying to run.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. I'm using a virtual environment and all the packages are being installed correctly into the virtual environment. However when I try to run the code within the virtual environment, it gives me a module not found error, are these 2 different python paths? and how do I solve this? thank youu

Comment: @casualcoder After activating your virt env, check if it is successful with: `which python` and `pip -V`. It must be showing your virt env.