# Using my virtual environment - where is python?

Tags: python

I'm an extreme newbie with regards to Python, and I'm following [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)
to get started. I've been struggling to get my virtual environment to work. I'm able to get to installing the packages (step 3 in the "Install and use packages" section) but when I then try to run the import lines after installing the packages in my virtual environment I still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'` and same for numpy.

When I navigate in File Explorer I can find a folder called .venv in my project folder, and within it Lib/site-packages seems to have the modules that I'm looking for. Which makes me think I'm not correctly using the virtual environment. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057252/modulenotfounderror-after-pip-install-on-venv) that some people had this problem when they were in the wrong Python environment, so I tried typing `where python` but I didn't really get...anything?

[image: where python result]

My guess is I'm missing something very fundamental/obvious but I can't figure out what it is!

Comment: "Which makes me think I'm not correctly using the virtual environment" - Why is this?

Comment: @Sayse since the modules I want seem to be in the folder where the virtual environment is stored

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the real answer of your question, but this may help. It have a good compatibility with Visual Studio Code too.

Here is the step I used everytime I create a virutal environement :

First, as one time install, I need to install [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) globaly with :

```sh
$ pip install pipenv
```

Next, everytime I need to create a virtual environement for the project I'm in I just use these command :

```sh
$ pipenv shell
$ pip install python_package_name
```

Note that `pipenv shell` will create a new virtual environement if it doesn't exist or activate the existing one.

To activate it in the project folder, just retype this is enough :

```sh
$ pipenv shell
```

You can read more about pipenv [here](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Comment: ooo this looks great, I'll let you know how it goes!